# How customze filter in rails active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to filter report weekly ,monthly and yearly?
I want to add 3 filter one is weekly second one is monthly and 3rd is yearly and option for select year for which i am filtering data.
[image]

Comment: can you add the code snippet you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

visit below link this is perfect example for create custom filters

http://nikhgupta.com/code/activeadmin/custom-filters-using-ransacker-in-activeadmin-interfaces/